# Multiple User type with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

Using Django we have two types of Users (Teachers and Students) with common fields and uncommon fields

In our wizard we first POST the common fields to /users with an extra `type_field`
Every operation after this should be able to figure out which model (Teacher or Student) it needs to use.

We are thinking of making two models ( Teacher and Student ) with an one-to-one field.

But how do we hookup the `type_field` to the right Model on every operation?

Comment: Do you mean that you use `type_field` to differentiate between student and teacher objects? (with `type_field` a param sent by your form to `/users`)

Comment: On first create of the user we ask them to select there type and fill in basic stuff like name and email, which will fit in Django's User model.
But all operation after this needs to grab the right USER profile to ask them to fill in the uncommon fields

Comment: Please take a look at the answer below and let me know if it fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   # more common fields

class Student(Person):
   specific_field_to_student = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   # more fields


class Teacher(Person):
   specific_field_to_teacher = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   # more fields
```

In your database you will have 3 tables (`yourapp_person`, `yourapp_student` and `yourapp_teacher`). Now, if `type_field` value is student, you will use `Student` model to create user, if it is teacher, you will use `Teacher` model.

**Note:** You may need to make `Person` model above a subclass of the built-in `User` model.

**Edit:**

I have edited the model above to take into account the requirements in the comments below.

Now, to retrieve user by id, you can use the following code in your view:

```
user = Person.objects.get(id=id)  # id is the view param
if hasattr(user, 'student'):
    print("Student")
else:  # hasattr(user, 'teacher')
    print("Teacher")
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but how do you do the selection if I for example request a GET /users/4. Is that something you put into a serializer or make some middleware?

Comment: You do not have any extra information sent with your request to know the object type (student or teacher)?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to go for an extra field since you are already having two different classes for students and teachers. A simple approach may looks like below.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Teacher(User):
    extra_field_1 = models.Fieldtype()
    ...
    ...

class Student(User):
    extra_field_1 = models.Fieldtype()
    ...
    ...
```

You can provide both type of users same registration form and upon clicking next take them to next page based on the value of I am a teacher/student field. In that case I suggest you to use [atomic blocks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/) if you dont want to save data in case registration procedure fails at some point or user have selected a wrong choice and they want to go back.  By this approach each inherited models have `username, first_name, last_name and email` that you dont have to insert any of these to Teacher or student model.
Then you have to create [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) for each model. You may use [modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) A much better approach will be using [class based views](http://ccbv.co.uk) since that reduce a lot of code and stick to [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles.

Comment: But how do I know which Model to use when I request a GET user /user/5 for example?

Comment: instead of /user/{id} , use `/teacher/{id}`. If it is must for you to use /usr/{id}, then you have to fetch a teacher object with reference from user object. May be it looks like this `if teacher.user.id == user.id:`.

Comment: well if a user logs in you don't know if he is a student or teacher, so using general /user/{id} is the only option right?

Comment: A straight-forward approach will be, instead of using custom models to handle roles (and permissions), You should use django's built-in `group-permission framework`. Create groups named teachers and students. Add user to the group. Upon logging in you can check the group of logged in user using `teacher=Group.objects.get('teacher'); if teacher in request.user.groups.all()`.